# Using docker-compose to mount volume that will change across hosts

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-volume

In docker compose I know you can set volume binds by putting something like

```
volumes:
    - /some_path_on_host:/some_path_in_container
```

However the /some_path_on_host for me will be different based on the host machine

I tried looking in docker documentation and couldn't find anything specific to this case.

Basically I want to make sure that even someone without any docker experience can set the path for the volume on the host machine, without having to edit docker-compose.

From my understanding Docker also allows paths to be set with environment variables which can be seen [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/)

```
volumes:
    - ${SOME_ENV_VAR}:/some_path_in_container
```

Is there any other way to set volumes that is more user friendly or should I just tell them to set SOME_ENV_VAR? Would using the SOME_ENV_VARIABLE be best practice?

Comment: The single easiest answer here would be to use a path relative to the `docker-compose.yml` file, `’./foo:/some_path_in_container’`, if an isolated tree per installation will work.

Comment: @David The location of the **host path** may be different on each machine even relative to the docker-compose file so on one host machine it could be `/path` on another it could be `/a/much/deeper/path` it wont always be in the same place relative to docker-compose.yml